Calculating impedance to convert vRMS to dBm
I am modifying a car radio to add bluetooth, and one of my concerns is making sure that the audio signal I am injecting will not damage the radio. I have used my oscilloscope to measure the standard audio input into the dolby noise reduction chip (which is the first IC the audio will go into) at around 10mV peak amplitude whilst playing a 50hz sine tone. The datasheet for this chip says the input should be -30dBm. How am I supposed to work out the impedance of the load so I can calculate what my maximum peak input voltage should be, as the bluetooth module I have won't quite produce a 10mV signal, the lowest it goes is around 30mV. 


If you assumed 50 ohm, what voltage do you get?

Sorry, not sure what you mean - why would I assume 50 ohm? I didn't assume any resistance.

@S.Stevens Which chip that is? The scan is very poor. Also dBm is a logarithmic unit of power. Into some load. Which means there needs to be some impedance that will dissipate -30dBm at some voltage. We don't know what that impedance is and if the unit is really dBu which assumes same voltage as 0 dBm into 600 ohm load which is typical.

If the chip is Sony CXA1102, the data sheet defines the following:
0dBm = 0.775Vrms.
As dBm means 1mW into 600 ohms, it also means they are really not talking about dBm but dBu which are equivanent in voltage unloaded, into high impedance.
The data sheet further defines -30dBm to be 24.5 mVrms which matches the other definition.

I believe you meant 24.5 mV not 24.5V.

Thank you, interestingly that 24.5mVrms gives a peak voltage of 34.65mV, whereas I see around 10-15mV...not sure what's going on there
